# Disclaimer that covers everything in condensed wording

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, word-order

Let’s say I wanted to set up a comedy show using a particularly vulgar comedian. The comedian in this show would primarily use comedy insulting or degrading to individuals or organisations.

I would need to let the audience know what they were in for and that it is all in good fun. I’m trying to write a disclaimer to illustrate to all that what is said is not serious and is only said for entertainment and comedy.

I need to emphasise the show is for adults only and has:

- Comments about race/religion/politics/individuals extremely degrading
- Other Offensive material
- Vulgar language
- Possibly (fantasy/non-realistic) violent imagery

Also, and this is the hard bit, emphasise that comments are in no way serious and just for entertainment as the scenario and platform for this show is realistic and people could easily mistake for being genuine. As if it were not a stand-up show in this respect.

All this needs to be said as condensed as possible, a paragraph or two max.

Comment: I want to help you with this, but my spidey senses are tingling to tell me a mod is going to call this question off-topic and ask you to move it elsewhere. Moreover, you seem to have all the elements of an answer to your question within the body of the question. I'll take a stab at it, though: "Tonight's show contains material you might find offensive. We'd like to emphasize that this is a comedy performance, and all the comments you hear tonight are in no way serious and are just meant in jest. Enjoy!"

Comment: You can say the comic [*works blue*](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-color_humor), and is for adults only.

Comment: @WilliamBloom I was not sure where to put this on the site. English Language & Usage seemed the most appropriate Thanks for the comment tho seems perfect.

Comment: I was rolling in the aisles, @William Bloom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would put it this way:

> WARNING: Extended satirical material on this program may strike some viewers as vulgar, offensive, prurient, or (worst of all) serious. It's satire. Please adjust your expectations and interpretations accordingly.